# How to prove that a recursive sequence with a square root produces positive integers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, integers

I have been looking at the sequence defined by $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + \sqrt{3a_n^2 - 2}$ for any n where n is a natural number. I am trying to prove that all of the terms in the sequence are positive integers. I can prove that they're positive, but I am having trouble proving that they're integers. I tried squaring both sides to try and get rid of the root, but that didn't work. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried proving it by induction?

Comment: It's best to guess a formula for $a_n$ based on the first few terms, then do as @JohnWaylandBales said. Have you worked out any terms?

Comment: As JG suggests ... Calculate the firsy few values & see if you recognise the sequence https://oeis.org/A001835